# How to get exact number from text field in sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table including Customer_Contact_No, Name, Income. I want to get customer net income as a value from income column. 
[image]

Final output should like below. There are 100000+ rows in my table.
[image]

AF-4838 - Mr.Gayan is a Doctor and his salary- RS.95000/-. He has a coconut land and monthly income is Rs.150000/-. his expenses – Rs.55000 and his Net Income – Rs.190000/-

AV-7392 - Monthly Net income is 55000/-

AF-3746 - Wife’s salary –Rs 25000, He is a shop owner and monthly income from shop = Rs 100000/- and Net Income for the month is Rs. 80000/- after expenses of Rs.45000

AF-6453 - Total Monthly net income is 60000/

Comment: Given the nature of the text, SQL Server is not the right tool.  Do something in your favorite language (such as Python) for parsing the strings.

Comment: If you are open to a UDF, I may have a solution for you, but you'll need to supply the sample data as text rather than an image

Comment: Mr John. how can i send it to you

Comment: Just edit your question and paste the 4 rows illustrated above as text

Comment: ok, i did Mr John

Comment: OK - just a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @test table
(
    val varchar(300)
)

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah blah blah net income blah blah 86000'

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah blah blah net income blah blah 4000, expenses 0'

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah blah blah net income blah blah 80,000 g'

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah expenses are 60 blah blah net income blah blah 6000 blah '

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah net income for whatever 6000. blah blah net income blah blah 86000'

select replace(substring(val,0, CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',val) = 0 THEN len(val) + 1 ELSE PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',val) END),',','') as NetIncomes
from
(
    select substring(val, inc, len(val) - inc + 1) as val
    from
    (
        select substring(val,net,len(val) - net + 1) as val, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',substring(val,net,len(val) - net + 1)) as inc
        from
        (
            select val, len(val) - charindex('emocni ten', reverse(val)) as  net
            from @test
        )q
    )q2
)q3
```

You could also do this with CTE's if you prefer

```
declare @test table
(
    val varchar(300)
)

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah blah blah net income blah blah 86000'

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah blah blah net income blah blah 4000, expenses 0'

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah blah blah net income blah blah 80,000 g'

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah expenses are 60 blah blah net income blah blah 6000 blah '

INSERT INTO @test 
select 'blah net income for whatever 6000. blah blah net income blah blah 86000'


;WITH FindNetIncomeString AS (select val, len(val) - charindex('emocni ten', reverse(val)) as  net from @test),
      FindFirstNumeric AS (select substring(val,net,len(val) - net + 1) as val, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',substring(val,net,len(val) - net + 1)) as inc from FindNetIncomeString),
      GetNumericOnly AS (select substring(val, inc, len(val) - inc + 1) as val from FindFirstNumeric),
      GetNetIncome as (select replace(substring(val,0, CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',val) = 0 THEN len(val) + 1 ELSE PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',val) END),',','') as NetIncomes from GetNumericOnly)
select NetIncomes
from GetNetIncome;
```

Result

```
NetIncomes
------
86000
4000
80000
6000
86000
```

Test with non-CTE: http://rextester.com/LGFW6563

Test with CTE: http://rextester.com/SRTG30852

Comment: my data set have thousand determiner values like 8,600
4,000
80,000
6,000 then the code give output as 8 , 4 , 80 , 6, how can fix this

Comment: assume - Monthly Net income from Transport service is 55000/- and expenses 20000/- and Net income is 30000/- i am using non CTE code, and it reading values from top to bottom, then it take Net income value as 55000. but its wrong. how can i get Net Income As 30000

Comment: hmm - do you want me to make it just find the LAST occurrence of "net income" and go on that?  Or what would you suggest for parsing?

Comment: hmmm yes tried various ways to get last Net Income value. but i couldn't do it, can you please

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested CHARINDEX functions to get the first numeric value after the starting point of the substring, "net income".

Comment: Also after the substring for charIndex (string, 'net income',field length) u might want to strip out all non numerics

Answer (score 0):

The UDF will extract strings based on two non-like delimiters

You may notice that I replace "Net Income" with "||Net Income"  I do this so that my first delimeter will be "|||" and and also add a "/" to the end of the string for my second delimter of "/".  This is ensure that the string has at least one "/"

**Example**

```
Select A.customer_contact_no
      ,Income = try_convert(int,right(B.RetVal,charindex(' ',replace(reverse(RetVal),'.',' '))-1))
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](replace([Income],'Net Income','|||Net Income')+'/','|||','/') B
 Where RetVal Like 'Net Income%'
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: 100000+ rows i have, how can i insert into @YourTable?

Comment: @YohanDe The (at)YourTable is just a table variable use for illustration / demonstration.

Comment: @YohanDe Use an OUTER APPLY if you want to see NULLs

Comment: how can i use outer apply? didnt use it before

Comment: @YohanDe Replace CROSS APPLY with OUTER APPLY